# call dynamic function javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var VariableName = {
    Test: function () {
        alert("test");
    }
};
window["VariableName.Test"]();
```

This  give error. how to call test function?

Comment: Assuming you declared `VariableName` in global scope, `window['VariableName']['Test']()` or `window.VariableName.Test()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use strings for the object and property names, you can do it like this:

```
window["VariableName"]["Test"]();
```

But, if you already know the names, it can just be this:

```
window.VariableName.Test();
```

or this if only the `Test` name is know ahead of time:

```
window["VariableName"].Test();
```